# Angular Material DateTimepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using this http://logbon72.github.io/angular-material-datetimepicker/ (Angular Material Date Time picker)
It works well when only one is present

```
<md-input-container flex-gt-md="200">
    <input time="false" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker type="text" id="date"
           placeholder="Posting Date" format="YYYY-MM-DD"
           ng-model="posting_date" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate">
</md-input-container>
```

But it fails when I code like this in (ng-repeat)

```
<div ng-repeat="JobExp in jobpostings">
    <md-input-container flex-gt-md="200">
        <input time="false" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker type="text" id="date"
               placeholder="Posting Date" format="YYYY-MM-DD" md-select="changed()"
               ng-model="JobExp.posting_date" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate">
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

I tried calling md-select function but it doesnt call nor ng-select
I tried using $watch like this

```
$scope.$watch("JobExp.posting_date", function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.JobExp.posting_date = $filter('date')(new Date($scope.JobExp.posting_date), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    console.log("PostinDate:"+$scope.JobExp.posting_date);

});
```

It says cannot read the property of undefined near posting_date

What mistake I am doing ? How to achieve this ?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle to show your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

One problem which I see is that, in your `ng-repeat`, for all the date-picker, the `ng-model` is `JobExp.posting_date` . Which is logically wrong because all your datepickers will be binded to one scope variable and changing one will change the value in all the others.

You should consider using separate`ng-model` for each datepicker. You can have separate `ng-model` like this:

```
<input time="false" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker type="text" id="date"
           placeholder="Posting Date" format="YYYY-MM-DD" md-select="changed()"
           ng-model="posting_date{{$index}}" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate">
```

This will give you separate `ng-model` for each datepicker like this:
`posting_date0`, `posting_date1` and so on...

In order to put a watch on all the models, you can create a watch on collection like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('[posting_date0, posting_date1]', function(newValues, oldValues){
  // do stuff here
  // newValues and oldValues contain the new and respectively old value
  // of the observed collection array
});
```

Comment: Thnaks,But how do I achieve this dynamically

Comment: I have updated my answer to achieve dynamic ng-model. have a look.

Comment: ok got it,But if I want to write a $watch on each individual item then how to code ?

Comment: But I dont know How many posting_date variables will be created then ?

Comment: posting_date variables will be same in number as length of jobpostings. So you can loop over jobpostings and create an array of posting_date.

Comment: Actly I am new to angularjs, would you please post a snippet for this ?

Comment: How to achieve this ? @ashfaq.p